# Android Search Interface and Material Design

Tags: android, material-design, android-search

Is the [Android Search Interface](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html) as it is implemented in the Documentation still up-to-date for the new `Toolbar` which was Introduced in Android 5 with `AppCompatActivity` and Material Design? Or is this still a solution for the old ActionBar(e.g. from `ActionBarActivity`)?

Comment: read the material design guidelines https://www.google.com/design/spec/patterns/search.html#search-in-app-search

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your question, no it's not up to date with the new design. But that doesn't mean you can't figure out how to do the task with the new design and toolbar. But no it's not updated.